# Пескарь и Пискарь

Tags: орфография

Известно название мелкой рыбки "пескарь". Но у М.Е.Салтыкова-Щедрина сказка называется "Премудрый пискарь".Так писалось это слово в 19 веке или причина в другом?

Comment: Когда берёшь пискаря в кулак, что бы снять с крючка, он издаёт писк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классической литературе известны написания “лебядь”, “рясницы”, “имянины”, “масляница”,  “снигирь”, “поцалуй”, “итти”, “жолтый”, “чорт”, “язычёк”, “безконечный”, “черезчур”, имена типа “Катинька”, “Ваничка” — их сохраняют некоторые издания. Подобные варианты слов, порожденные непоследовательностью прежних правил*, знакомы культурному человеку по литературной классике XVIII—XIX веков и первой половины ХХ века. Они хранят память о словесности ушедших эпох, и этим определяется их стилистическая окраска — та окраска, которой подобные слова не имели, пока не стали архаизмами. До 1956 г. можно было писать, например, “метель” и “мятель”, “пескарь” и “пискарь”, “мачеха” и “мачиха.В авторском написании слова «пискарь», содержится элемент уничижительной характеристики героя. Готовый пищать от страха «пискарь» олицетворяет собой интеллигента-либерала, трусливо устранившегося от активной борьбы и даже от самой жизни. В более поздних изданиях это исчезло, исчез и этот акцент.Может, посчитали лишним, иронии и без него хватает. Может, чтобы школьники при изучении ошибок не делали.Была такая методика: только грамотное написание. Пушкина только побоялись поправить с его "он ещё в постеле".

Answer (score 4):

Согласно нормам правописания XIX века, слово «пескарь» в этой сказке традиционно пишется через «и» — «пискарь», в том числе в современных академических (с комментариями) изданиях Салтыкова-Щедрина. Некоторые детские иллюстрированные неакадемические издания называют главного героя согласно современным нормам - «пескарь».

(Вики)

Comment: Спасибо за емкий ответ, но в нем не хватает Ваших размышлений о том, в чем причина такой трансформации. "Пискарь" - от "писк" ? "Пескарь" - от "песок"? Я в затруднении.

Comment: Пескарь - от песок. Они по дну песчаному плавают.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием, но не знаю. Современное "пескарь" действительно связывают с песком, но недостоверно. Что же касется старой формы, то она для меня полная загадка. Я не верю "народной" этимологии, что дескать эта рыба издаёт звуки, похожие на писк.

Comment: Меня тоже смущает этот "писк", а еще больше то, что в названии сказки С-Щедрина осталось слово с буквой "и" в современных изданиях, причем не только в академических.

Comment: Вот начет изданий - не понял. Почему надо менять, если у М.Е. именно так?

Comment: Оказывается, версия "пискарь" от писк есть у Брема. Может, правда, пищит эта животная?! Суффикс "-арь" в общем-то вполне продуктивен в подобных образованиях.

Comment: Да. Фасмер тоже ссылается на Брема.
пискарь - пескарь, род. п. -я, диал. пискал, пескал – то же, укр. пискiр, болг. пискал (Младенов 424), сербохорв. пискор "мурена", словен. piskor, -rja, piskor, piskur "минога (речная)", чеш. piskor "речной вьюн", слвц. piskor, польск. piskorz, в.-луж., н.-луж. piskor, -rjа – то же. Вероятно, связано с писк, пищать, потому что пескарь, если его схватить рукой, издает своеобразный звук (Брем);

Comment: Я через Фасмера на Брема и вышел. Вроде бы в детстве я эту рыбку ловил, не помню, чтобы она пищала.

Comment: @behemothus Это какая-то путаница. Словом пескарь (пискарь) называли разных рыб: собственно пескаря обыкновенного и ещё вьюна обыкновенного. Если посмотрите у Фасмера, там очевидно, что речь идёт о вьюне (на других языках: минога, вьюн, вьюн, вьюн). Про вьюна общеизвестно, что он пищит (см. Брема, Вики и вообще). И никакой другой пискарь у Брема не пищит. В многотомных толковых словарях приводятся латинские названия этих рыб, что помогает избежать недоразумений.

Comment: @grizzly Это все, конечно, хорошо, но вопросу этому уж восемь лет без малого. Восстанавливать свои тогдащшние мысли нга биологические темы тяжеловато сейчас. Меня больше интересует, какого из пискарей тогда имел в виду Михаил Евграфович?

Comment: Я не призываю Вас спорить на биологические темы :) Я просто добавил к ответу справочную информацию, поскольку люди это до сих пор читают (на другом форуме меня отослали сюда с аргументом, что "пескарь от писка"). В сказке описан вьюн, конечно.

Comment: @grizzly *В сказке описан вьюн, конечно* - а вот тут хотелось бы аргументов. Смущает, что пищать-то вьюн пищит, но про то, что его пискарем называют как-то очень мало подробностей. И, если не секрет, ссылочку на дискуссию "на другом форуме".

Comment: Там ничего особо интересного в обсуждении (и я сам не сразу разобрался). [Здесь](https://dxdy.ru/post1477719.html#p1477719) я отвечаю на такую же просьбу дать ссылку на то, что вьюна пискарём называли. В сказке сам образ жизни ГГ очень похож на образ жизни вьюна (живёт в иле, а не на песке, прячется в норы).

Comment: @grizzly "В сказке сам образ жизни ГГ очень похож на образ жизни вьюна" - о как! А говорите, что "не призываю Вас спорить на биологические темы". )))  Ясно, спасибо. то есть получается, что все художники (ну из мне известных) сильно путаются в иллюстрациях. Рыбки-то совсем разные. Осталось найти какое подтверждение авторитетное, что вьюна того действительно пискарем кличут. Не мог же С-Щ совсем уж диалектное словечко вставить.

Comment: Я же сослался на Брокгауза и -Ефрона, Вам этого мало?! Я так и предполагал, поэтому решил привести ещё миллион косвенных аргументов. Я был наивен :)

Comment: @grizzly *Я же сослался на Брокгауза и -Ефрона, Вам этого мало?!* - не вижу этой ссылки. Это на "другом форуме"?

Comment: Да, в том конкретном сообщении, на которое я ссылался выше и про которое говорил, что оно посвящено этому вопросу. Добавлю сюда [тоже](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/80009).

Comment: @grizzly Н-да... Одно могу сказать: заставили вы меня крепко задуматься. Как же возникла-то эта путаница? Как получилось-то, что две совершенно разные рыбки получили сходное название - и об этом до вас никто и не догадывался? Да и сам автор ПП не озаботился возможным недоразумением?

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл любопытную версию. Слово ***"пискарь"*** выводят ещё к праиндоевропейскому корню **pisḱ-** (что значит -- **рыба**).

Помните, как на латинском называется знак Зодиака *Рыбы* ? *Pisces*. А по-английски тоже немного похоже: *рыба* -- *fish*. Решил я посмотреть в Wiktionary этимологию лат. слова *Pisces*. Он меня отослал к ПИЕ корню. Там список слов на разных языках, происходящих от этого корня. И в конце -- русский пискарь.

Вот я и вспомнил об этом обсуждении на форуме "Русский язык".

P.S. Что-то ссылка в тексте не работает. Напишу ещё отдельно.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/pisḱ-

Comment: Спасибо, Николай, очень интересно!

Comment: Насчет сведения английского fish к латинскому - это вряд ли, хотя фонетическое соответствие действительно есть. А вот с пискарем - это интересно...

Хотя пардон, они не выводят из латинского, они говорят о ПИЕ-родстве... 
Впрочем, все равно непонятно... Столь древний корень не мог изолированно сохраниться только в русском (из славянских). Только заимствование. Но тогда не проходит идея латино-германского родства. Думать надо...

Comment: Это ничего не добавляет к викшенари. 
Меня еще суффикс крепко настораживает. "-арь" для ИЕ-морфа непонятно...

Comment: >>Меня еще суффикс крепко настораживает. "-арь"
 
Да, я тоже над суффиксом задумался. Похож на германский. Или и исконно славянский такой может быть? Вот не знаю (пекарь, пахарь, к примеру).

Потом, больше ничего "рыбного" славянского с корнем писк- не вспомню. (Это если критически подойти к данной версии). Правда, бывают слова, вышедшие из употребления.

Comment: Ну что Вы, именно что славянский. бондарь, чеботарь, вратарь. Даже букварь. Это-то и странно. "Пискарь" тогда не рыба, а тот, кто имеет отношение к рыбе. Пискарь от писка вполне бы укладывалось.

Comment: @grumant, вы можете вспоминать все что угодно, но мы говорим о конкретном слове, ПИЕ-корне "pisk" (рыба) и конкретном суффиксе "-aрь" (тот кто имеет к ней отношение) - и это все увязать. Все ваши словарные знания не имеют к нему никакого отношения. Аналогии нет никакой.

Answer (score 2):

Если пискарь ошибочно, то почему ПИскарёвское кладбище? Или это не из этой оперы?

Comment: Написание топонимов может не следовать правилам.
Тем более, если топоним построен на фамилии.

Answer (score 1):

Верны оба варианта написания.  Это два разных названия одной рыбы:  пескарь - от песок (так как зачастую эта рыбка держится мест с песчаным дном);   пискарь - от слова "писк", "пищать"  (пойманная рыбка издаёт скрежещуще-пищащие звуки)

Answer (score 0):

насчет пискаря не скажу, но -арь - мне кажется, скорее индоевропейский суффикс, чем чисто славянский. Думаю, что -арь похож на европейский -er (baker - тот же пекарь).